# Replace file name with simple python regex script (for Automator)

Tags: python, regex, automator

I would like to create an automator folder action to rename files that I add in.

Basically, my files are named like that :

```
SOMETEXT-A00B00-ANOTHERTEXT.extension
```

To create and run an automator action that rename a file isn't a problem, but I would like to use regex (in Python if possible, 'cause i'm not familiar with apple script or batch) to rename the file like that :

```
A00B00.extension
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If that structured name stands as a rule, in Python it is easier to use split than regex for such a case.

```
filename = 'SOMETEXT-A00B00-ANOTHERTEXT.extension'
base = filename.split('-')[1]
extension = filename.split('.')[1]
new_filename = base + '.' + extension
print new_filename
```

result

> A00B00.extension